# How to sync drawings in TradingView chart ilb

Tags: javascript, charts, tradingview-api

Im using TradingView chart lib and wanted to now how to sync drawings between charts

```
new TradingView.widget({
            "width": 980,
            "height": 610,
            "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
            "interval": "D",....
```

so when adding drawing(icons or etc) in one chart I want to dublicate in other chart his OTC option